# Show field conditionally + display each form part in div

Tags: theming, forms

I've followed the tutorial in order to create field conditionnaly, but the field is always shown.

This is possibly due to the way I'm calling my form ? And if I do as I did in my template, how can I have my input in bootstrap's column and keeping the conditional rules ?

This is my form builder:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $form['#theme'] = 'contract_search';
    $classes_input = ['form-control'];

    $form['colour_select'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => $this->t('Pick a colour'),
      '#options' => [
        'blue' => $this->t('Blue'),
        'white' => $this->t('White'),
        'black' => $this->t('Black'),
        'other' => $this->t('Other'),
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        //define static name and id so we can easier select it
        // 'id' => 'colour_select',
        'name' => 'colour_select',
      ],
    ];

    $form['custom_colour'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => '60',
      '#placeholder' => 'Enter favourite colour',
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => 'custom-colour',
      ],
      '#states' => [
        //show this textfield only if the radio 'other' is selected above
        'visible' => [
          //don't mistake :input for the type of field. You'll always use
          //:input here, no matter whether your source is a select, radio or checkbox element.
          ':input[name="field_select_colour"]' => ['value' => 'other'],
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

My controller method :

```
  public function contract_add() {

    $form_class = '\Drupal\contract_search\Form\ContractSearchForm';
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form_class);
    return [
      '#theme' => 'contract_add_page_theme',
      '#title' => 'Déposer une annonce',
      '#form' => $form,
    ];

  }
```

my module routing

```
contract_search.contract_add:
  path: '/contrat/ajout'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\contract_search\Controller\ContractSearchController::contract_add'
    _title: Déposer une annonce
    _form: '\Drupal\contract_search\Form\ContractForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      reference:
        type: string
```

and finally my twig template

```
<section id="add_contract">
  {{ form }}
</section>
```

This is what is generated :
[image]

Comment: `['#states']['visible']` expects a CSS selector as keyname. There is no element machting `:input[name="field_select_colour"]` in your source code. Try `input[name="select_colour"]` instead

Comment: tried **colour_select** but still nothing changed, the "other" field is still showing